# Second Instance of firefox browser is not opening in selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am new to selenium. And I am trying to open multiple instances of firefox browser.

**I am not using any Grid**. And My selenium version is 2.47.1 and firefox version is 37.0.1.

**Also, my browser is not closing automatically even I used quit()**

Below is my code:

```
    package TestAutomation;

   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class TestClassOpenBrowser {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebDriver d2 = new FirefoxDriver();
    d2.get("http://yahoo.com");
    d2.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.quit();
    d2.quit();

}

 }
```

Comment: What is happening? Any errors on the console? What if you use `close()` instead of `quit()`? Have you tried with other firefox versions?

Comment: No errors on console. I tried with close() too. Not working. I even updated the firefox version. Still No result. could that be because of jar files?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that version 2.42.0 was probably the last version of Selenium that really supported Firefox native events (for Firefox 31).   Selenium 2.43 says it supports native events for Firefox32 but I don't think it really worked.   In general, if you are running local Firefox instances, you want to be using Firefox 31 or Firefox31.0.6 , even if your on Selenium 2.47+ .

Also, if you are having trouble managing multiple driver instances, take a look at how I did it here  (see the ShootoutSuiteTestBase.java
class) :
https://gist.github.com/djangofan/f5eda36f556fc55a5dcb

Answer (score 0):

Tried with jar file version 2.45.0. it worked. Issue was in the latest jar files 2.47.1